# Correctly displaying parsed MJML in a Laravel mailable class

Tags: laravel-9

I'm using [Spatie MJML package](https://github.com/spatie/mjml-php?tab=readme-ov-file) and this is what I have in my `content()` function of my `LeadCreatedWelcomeMail` class.

```
    public function content()
    {
        $preview_text = 'Your Test Drive Has Been Scheduled!';
        $lead = $this->lead;

        $html = Mjml::new()->toHtml(view("emails.lead-created", compact('lead', 'preview_text'))->render());

        return new Content(
            view: $html,
        );
    }
```

The MJML correctly gets parsed as html. How can I pass it to my `new Content` class to display the email. The way I'm doing above is erroring out.

Error: View [the html strings that gets produced] not found.